# Compose which callback runs on UI thread

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In [Compose docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel) there is

> Instead, trigger side-effects from callbacks such as onClick that always execute on the UI thread.

Which callback runs on UI thread on Compose? Is there a set of those?

Comment: Callbacks that triggers by user interaction always run on UI thread.